# Rails form multiple checkboxes for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm creating an application where a "submission" can be made using a form which creates client details and allows "referrals" to be created depending on the branch(es) that can provide the required service

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals, :inverse_of => :submission, dependent: :delete_all
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :referrals, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :referrals
end
```

Submissions controller:

```
def new
  @submission = Submission.new
  @submission.build_client
  @submission.client.build_address
  @submission.referrals.build
end

def submission_params
  params.require(:submission).permit(:consent, :user_id, client_attributes:
    [:client_id, :first_name,
      address_attributes:
        [:first_line, :second_line,]
    ],
    referrals_attributes:
      [:branch_id]
  )
end
```

The Submission form:

```
<%= form_for(@submission) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :referrals do |referral| %>
    <%= render 'referral_fields', f: referral %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

_referral_fields.html.erb:

```
    <% Branch.all.where(referrable: true).each do |branch| %>
       <label>
          <%= check_box_tag 'branch_ids[]', branch.id %>
          <%= branch.name %>
       </label>
    <% end %>
```

What I want is to have checkboxes for each referrable branch. When a branch is ticked and the submission is created, a referral will be created for that branch. However, when I submit the form, I get a validation error of "Referrals can't be blank". Any idea why this is not working?

Any help is most appreciated

Comment: Try changing `<%= check_box_tag 'branch_ids[]', branch.id %>` to `<%= f.check_box 'branch_id', branch.id %>`

Comment: Hi. Just tried that and still the same error

Comment: Sorry didnt fully get your changes.  I'm getting "undefined method `merge' for 1:Fixnum"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [collection_check_boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes).

```
<% # _referral_fields.html.erb %>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:branch_ids, Branch.where(referrable: true), :id, :name) do |b|
  b.label { b.check_box } # wraps check box in label
end %>
```

You would need to whitelist `submission[referrals_attributes][branch_ids]` - not `branch_id`.

```
def submission_params
  params.require(:submission)
    .permit(
      :consent, 
      :user_id, 
      client_attributes: [
        :client_id, 
        :first_name,
        address_attributes: [
          :first_line, :second_line,
        ]
    ],
    referrals_attributes: [:branch_ids]
  )
end
```

### Edited.

However for this to work you need to setup a relation between Referral and Branch. In this case you could use either a `has_and_belongs_to_many` (HABTM) or `has_many though:` (HMT) relationship.

See [Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

```
class Referral < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :submission
  has_and_belongs_to_many :branches
end

class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :referrals
end
```

You need to create a join table as well:

```
rails g migration CreateBranchReferralJoinTable branch referral
```

Comment: I get "undefined method `branch_ids' for #<Referral:0x007f33d537cbb0>"

Comment: Ah, its because you need to create a relation between Referral and Branch.

Comment: I already have that. branch has many referrals and referral belongs to branch

Comment: Yeah, but that won't work unless referral can have only one branch - and in that case you should not use a multiple checkboxes.

Comment: You see in the first case you putting `.branch_id` on the `referrals` table - with makes it one-to-many - what you need is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: the copypasta got the best of me in the edit - should of course be `Branch  has_and_belongs_to_many :referrals`. Edited.

Comment: Each checkbox needs to create a seperate referral. And yes, a referral cn only have one branch.  So for each branch that is selected, a referral with a specific branch_id should be created.  SOrry if my explanation didn't make that clear.

Comment: There is no easy way to do that in a plain HTML form in rails. And this case you really should not be trying to mosh everything into a single controller action. Split it up into multiple actions and use AJAX to make it appear seamless.

Comment: You can hack it and loop through input from the checkboxes but I just would'nt. Its to much of a mess.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll likely use cocoon to add referrals dynamically and use a select input to chose the required branch.  Thanks for the help though. I learnt a lot in the process